# How can I have multiple colors and text of the /tellraw in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-commands

I'm using /tellraw to make myself be happy for my map on some of the stuffs i needed for command blocks, but I can't do some of the Multiple colors and text like from the other maps with the names "" and using colored chat. (By the way DrStranger is just an example, but I still need some help thou.)

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Solution: Go to the Minecraft wiki, search for "tellraw", there's a link to "JSON", that page tells you everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can not only make colored text, but also add different stuff like bold, underline, italic etc.

In order to make it just put:

```
{"text":"mytext","color":"...",...}
```

after each and separate with commas. E.G

```
/tellraw @a ["",{"text":"first","color":"red"},{"text":"second","color":"green"},{"text":"third","color":"blue"},{...},...]
```

Or just use generator to make it more easier: http://minecraft.tools/en/tellraw.php